# Nhibernate QueryOver. Eager fetch with JoinAlias

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

How can I do Eager fetch using JoinAlias? 
I have the following query:

```
QueryOver<Ticket>()
    .JoinAlias(ticket => ticket.Agent, () => agent)
    .JoinAlias(ticket => ticket.Activities, () => activity)
    .Left.JoinAlias(ticket => ticket.BusinessUnit, () => unit) .... 
    .List<Ticket>();
```

I need this joins for complex filter logic that is not important for this question. This query generates such SQL:

```
FROM
       Requests.Ticket this_ INNER JOIN Requests.TicketsActivity activity2_
       ON this_.ID
          = 
          activity2_.TicketId
                             INNER JOIN Support.Agent agent1_
       ON this_.AgentID
          = 
          agent1_.ID
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN Requests.BusinessUnit unit3_
       ON this_.BusinessUnitId
          = 
          unit3_.ID
```

That what I need. But when I try to access one of the related entities (that was already joined), Nhibernate **makes a new lazy query**. How to prevent this?

I can add for each relation this:

```
QueryOver<Ticket>().Fetch(ticket => ticket.Activities).Eager.Future();
```

This solution solves the problem but adds new query with outer joins to existent ones described above. *"And when one head was cut off, the place where it was severed put forth two others"*

**Update:**

The problem can be solved to change all joins to outer. Is it possible to do it with inner one?

Comment: I too am experiencing this problem. I can only eager load on left outer joins. But, I need to eager load using an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

I have came across this before, I do not believe it is by design as I have never got any real explanation for it.

See [this](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.ie/2011/09/queryover-eager-loading-parent-and.html):

I think we're stuck with this for now.